# Testing method with switch-case using Given-When-Then pattern

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, legacy-code

I have legacy code containing code which looks a bit like this:

```
public bool Execute(MyArgument arg)
{
    if(arg.Condition)
    {
        switch(arg.Data)
        {
            case DataValue.A:
            case DataValue.B:
            case DataValue.C:
                return false;   
            case DataValue.F:
            case DataValue.G:
            case DataValue.H:
                return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        arg.DoSomeStuff();
        return true;
    }
}
```

We're using Given-When-Then pattern, my question is should I test it with tests like these :

> Given NewContext When Execute with Condition True and DataValue A Then
>   return false
>
> Given NewContext When Execute with Condition True and DataValue B Then
>   return false
>
> Given NewContext When Execute with Condition True and DataValue C Then
>   return false
>
> Given NewContext When Execute with Condition True and DataValue D Then
>   return true
>
> Given NewContext When Execute with Condition True and DataValue E Then
>   return true
>
> Given NewContext When Execute with Condition True and DataValue F Then
>   return true
>
> Given NewContext When Execute with Condition False  Then DoSomeStuff
>   should be called Then return true

Or do you see any better approach? (If you think my tests are valid, do not hesitate to say so in the comments).

Comment: Thx for your comment, we're using NUnit and NSubstitute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you've got is fine. Personally, I'd favor verbosity over something shorter but much less clear. At least it'll be obvious exactly what you're testing.

You might consider taking advantage of the `TestCase` attribute in NUnit too.

```
[Test]
[TestCase(DataValue.A, false)]
[TestCase(DataValue.B, false)]
[TestCase(DataValue.C, false)]
[TestCase(DataValue.F, true)]
[TestCase(DataValue.G, true)]
[TestCase(DataValue.H, true)]
public void GetExpectedValueWhenConditionIsTrue(DataValue argData, bool expectedResult)
{
    var c = new YourClass();
    var arg = new MyArgument { Condition = true, Data = argData };

    var actualResult = c.Execute(arg);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```